# Fork後に歴史を消したリポジトリで歴史を復活させたい

Tags: git, github

ある程度コミットログがあるリポジトリをClone後に、コミットログを消して1からログを積み上げているというリポジトリがあります。
このリポジトリに、Clone元のコミットログを追加（復元？）する方法を探しております。

説明ができているか不安なので、下記にやりたい事の手順を記載致しました。
不明点などありましたらなるべく早く回答するように致します。
良い方法がありましたら教えてください。

### 再現手順

1. Gitでリポジトリ「repo1」を作り、いくつかコミットをした後にGitHubにpushします。
2. 「repo1」を「repo2」としてcloneし、「.git」を消します。
3. 「repo2」を再度Git管理します。（git init）
4. 「repo2」でいくつかコミットを行います。

   - first commitは「repo1」からcloneした時から変更はありません。
   - 歴史が1から作られます。
5. 「repo2」に「repo1」のコミットログを追加（復元？）したいです。

### 試したこと

- 一応以下の手順で復元ができることは確認できましたが、もっと良い方法（簡単な方法）があるのではないかと思っております。
- 「repo2」のFirst Commitの前に「repo1」のLast Commitを紐付けたいだけなので、方法がありそうだなと思っております。

---

```
git clone git@github.com:XXX/repo1.git repo1
cd repo1

git remote add git@github.com:XXX/repo2.git repo2

git checkout -b repo1_work
git branch remote/repo2/master repo2_work

git merge -Xtheirs --allow-unrelated-histories repo2_work
```

Comment: git replaceがまさにやりたい事でした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TR; DR

```
# 念のため壊れてもいいレポジトリで
git replace 新しいレポジトリ最初のコミット 古いレポジトリの最後のコミット
git filter-branch -- --all
```

## 詳細

git replace が利用できそうです。これは何かというと、(おそらく任意の)コミットの sha を指定したときに取得できる中身を、別のオブジェクトの中身から取得するようにするコマンドです。

具体例として、以下で作成されるレポジトリ repo1, repo2 があるとします。

```
rm -rf repo1 repo2

mkdir repo1
( cd repo1
  git init
  echo hoge > hoge
  git add hoge
  git commit -m "Initial"
  echo fuga >> hoge
  git add hoge
  git commit -m "Append fuga" )

git clone repo1 repo2
( cd repo2
  rm -rf .git
  git init
  git add -A
  git commit -m "Re-initialize"
  echo piyo >> hoge
  git add hoge
  git commit -m "Append piyo" )

( cd repo2
  git remote add repo1 ../repo1
  git fetch -p repo1 )

( cd repo1
  git log --graph > ../repo1-before.txt
)

( cd repo2
  git log --graph > ../repo2-before.txt
)
```

#### repo1-before.txt

```
* commit 87ee5eb689e4aa33c4b6816c501d89ee154658ea
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append fuga
|
* commit 7706f3beea43965c3dd92a9fcc914bbe4f91efbf
  Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
  Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000

      Initial
```

#### repo2-before

```
* commit 59a6096bdad4da18b1055fc66f49e4d54bc05be4
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append piyo
|
* commit 3fd04fd77a62b2f5471902eb0f020ade791c598c
  Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
  Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000

      Re-initialize
```

git レポジトリ上で `git replace sha_id content_sha_id` を実行すると、 `sha_id` の中身は、 `content_sha_id` の中身から取得するようになります。これは、このコマンドを実行したローカルレポジトリのみで有効です。

```
repo1_end=$(
    cd repo1
    git rev-parse HEAD )

repo2_init=$(
    cd repo2
    git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD )

( cd repo2
  git replace $repo2_init $repo1_end
)

# repo2 では、一時的に、 `.git/info/replace` が書き換えられ、
# repo2_init が repo1_end で解決されている。

( cd repo2
  git log --graph > ../repo2_replaced.txt # 確認する。
)
```

#### repo2_replaced

```
* commit 59a6096bdad4da18b1055fc66f49e4d54bc05be4
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append piyo
|
* commit 3fd04fd77a62b2f5471902eb0f020ade791c598c
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append fuga
|
* commit 7706f3beea43965c3dd92a9fcc914bbe4f91efbf
  Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
  Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000

      Initial
```

git の log を見て、問題がなければ、 `git filter-branch` を実行して、 replace を解決した形でコミットを実際に書き換えます。 これによって、 replace が解決された形でコミットが再生成されます。この状態になると、 push ができます。

```
# 問題なければ確定する
( cd repo2
  git filter-branch -- --all
  git log --graph > ../repo2_rewritten.txt
  git push repo1 master:repo2-master
)

( cd repo1
  git log --graph repo2-master > ../repo1_new_master.txt
)
```

#### repo1_new_master, repo2_rewritten (同じ内容)

```
* commit 0477c8800097110a858834f5711b2fcee1380cbc
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append piyo
|
* commit 87ee5eb689e4aa33c4b6816c501d89ee154658ea
| Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
| Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000
|
|     Append fuga
|
* commit 7706f3beea43965c3dd92a9fcc914bbe4f91efbf
  Author: Yuki INOUE <my.mail@domain.com>
  Date:   Fri Nov 3 11:47:18 2017 +0000

      Initial
```

この作業は、レポジトリのレビジョンの参照方法を途中で書き換えるので、壊れてもいいローカルレポジトリを用意して作業し、何かおかしくなってしまったら、レポジトリごと捨て去るのがいいと思います。